# Python: selection random number

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to understand principle of `random`  library's work.
I consider some situations:
1) I have value `b` and it can take the value `0` or `1` with probability `0.5`.
I know, that I can realize that with

```
numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(0, 2), p=[0.5, 0.5])
```

I want to understand, what steps are executed to choose some value?
It separates this segment and gets random value? 
How does it happen?

2) Or if I have, maybe a list. `lst = [1, 4, 7, 3, 254, 6, 2, 7, 3123, 454657, 34, 565, 99]`
I can you a common way to do that 
`random.choice(lst))`
but I want to understand too, what occurs during a decision?

Comment: in `choice()` you have list with 15 elements so `random` use `random.randint(15)` to choose  element - `lst[ random.randint( len(lst) ) ]`

Comment: Read [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l259)?

Comment: if you have probability `[0.25, 0.75]` then you choose from list `[0, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 4):

You should try opening the module if you want a full understanding of how it works. To do this you can use, in a python interpreter:

```
>>>import numpy
>>>help(numpy)
```

This will show some information on the document. You can find the function you are wondering about and read the code to understand how it works. I hope this helps.

Some more complex information on numpy is on this link aswell: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/

Remember, that it is not real random. Just pseudo random. The code uses a pseudo random number generator to generate random numbers.

Comment: Does that really show you the code? For `choice`, all this tells me is *"Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence"*, which doesn't help.

Comment: Yes.It should. It works for me when I use IDLE Python Shell.

Comment: I'm using IDLE Python Shell as well. Tried both Python 3 and Python 2. Doesn't show me the code.

Comment: I added a link which contains the whole file.

Comment: I hope it helps

Comment: I still think you're wrong. `help` isn't even supposed to show you the file. It's supposed to show you the help part. Which it does.

Comment: Code is also, from your install, in Lib/random.py. eg C:\Python27\Lib\random.py for me

Comment: Please note that the question is about numpy, which also takes a probability distribution array as an argument.

Comment: I editted my post to fit with numpy. I accidentally made a mistake and thought you were talking about random

Answer (score 2):

Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces 53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic purposes.Python doesn't actually generate random numbers: it gets them from the operating system, which has a special driver that gathers entropy from various real-world sources, such as variations in timing between keystrokes and disk seeks.
More info can be found in the python documentation.

Comment: Them here  is numbers